# Understanding the mean shift algorithm with Gaussian kernel

Tags: estimation, kernel-smoothing, mode

I am referring here to the [Wikipedia article regarding the mean shift algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean-shift).

Here the Gaussian kernel is denoted as $e^{-c\|x_i - x\|^2 }$

My questions are the following:

- Is $c$ always positive? I.e. are hence the "weights" given by the kernel always between 0 and 1?
- Looking at a picture explaining the algorithm, I have seen that in the two-dimensional case, the kernel can be understood as a circle..how do I see it from the formula above that it is indeed a circle, i.e. only points in this circle are considered at each iteration?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

if I were you I would refer to one of the main mean shift papers: [Mean Shift: A Robust Approach Toward Feature Space Analysis](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.869/handouts/PAMIMeanshift.pdf). The short answer to your questions: yes *c* is always positive and no the kernel (window) is not a circle.

Now the long version. The kernel density estimator is:
    $\hat{f}_h(x) = \frac{1}{nh} \sum_{i=1}^n K\Big(\frac{x-x_i}{h}\Big)$,

where K(•) is the kernel and *h* is called *bandwidth*. Your question is about two-dimensional data and in practice we usually have to deal with multivariate data and things are a bit trickier for multivariate data. That's why in Mean Shift we are only interested in a special case of radially symmetric kernels satisfying: $K(x)= c_{k,d} k(\|x\|^2)$ where $c_{k,d}$, the normalization constant, makes $K(x)$ integrate to one and $k(x)$ is called the *profile* of the kernel. It helps us simplify the calculation in the case of multivariate data.

The *profile* of the Gaussian kernel is:
$e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^{2}}$ and therefore, the multivariate Gaussian kernel with the standard deviation $\sigma$, will be:

$K(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma^d}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\|x\|^2}{\sigma^2}}$,

where $d$ is the number of dimensions. It's also worth mentioning that the standard deviation for the Gaussian kernel works as the bandwidth parameter, $h$.

Now having sample points $\{x_i\}_{i=1..n}$, each mean shift procedure starts from a sample point $y_j = x_j$ and update $y_j$ until convergence as follows:

$ {\displaystyle y_{j}^{t+1}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\|y_{j}^{t}-x_{i}\|^{2}}{\sigma^{2}}}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\|y_{j}^{t}-x_{i}\|^{2}}{\sigma^{2}}}}}$

So basically all the points are considered in calculation of the mean shift but there is a weight assigned to each point that decays exponentially as the distance from the current mean increases and the value of $\sigma$ determines how fast the decay is.